# Javascript Error: 'document' is not defined. [no-undef]

Tags: javascript

I'm an absolute beginner in JS.

**following is the Javascript code:**

```
   var blank = document.getElementsByClassName("my-input");

   var go = document.getElementById("go-button");

   console.log(blank);
   go.innerHTML = "Hello" + blank[0].value;
```

I use the IDE Brackets, whereas, I'm learning from a online course in which the teacher uses IDE Sublime text (he is not getting any errors)
I dont think IDE's make much of a difference, but mentioning.

**What I want to achieve is:**

A blank input box(with placeholder as "Your name") and a button (go button)
After typing the name, when we click the go button, text is displayed below the button as: `Hello {name}`

Comment: Could you provide your HTML as well

Comment: your js code looks correct, provide us with your `HTML` code

Comment: Your HTML needs to include elements with that class name and that id for this to work. And the script needs to be below the elements so the elements exist before the script runs. ( or you need to use a ready event, but let's not make it more complex than needed at first. )

Comment: @Aakriti Upadhyay, no issue with js and works fine with button click event -https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/rNBpxrj , some issue with your html

Answer (score 1):

This works, but you need to be sure to add an event listener, so the code can grab the input value after it has been entered by the user:

```js
var go = document.getElementById("go-button");

go.addEventListener("click", doFunc);

function doFunc() {
  var blank = document.getElementsByClassName("my-input");

  go.innerHTML = "Hello " + blank[0].value;
}
```

```html
<input class="my-input" /><br />
<input class="my-input" /><br />
<input class="my-input" /><br />
<button id="go-button">Go</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display the text below the button you need an element to select (or inject it right after the button element).

```js
 var blank = document.getElementsByClassName("my-input");
 var go = document.getElementById("go-button");
 
 go.addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.querySelector('.result').innerHTML = "Hello" + blank[0].value; 
 });
```

```html
<input class="my-input" />

<button id="go-button">click me</button>

<p class="result"></p>
```